# NodeJS Versioning Questions

Tags: node.js

Is there an explanation why NodeJS latest version is 6.2.1 but the LTS is 4.4.5? It might seem odd but shouldn't they stabilized version 5 first before working on or releasing version 6?
https://nodejs.org/en/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reasoning behind this is that Node works to a 'LTS schedule':

- New major version releases (i.e. the `x` in `x.y.z`) are created from the master branch every six months - even-numbered releases in April, odd-numbered releases in October.
- Whenever a new odd-numbered release comes out, the previous even-numbered release moves into LTS, meaning there should be no breaking changes to that version from that point on.
- The LTS version will be supported for 18 months, after which it will go into maintenance mode for 12 months, meaning it will only receive critical/security related updates. Because of this, there will never be more than two LTS versions active at the same time.

If it helps you visualize it, there's a diagram of the schedule on the Node LTS GitHub:

[image: LTS schedule]

This allows there to be a predictable release schedule and migration path for those who have to support their Node infrastructure long-term, while keeping the pace of development moving for those who want to stay on the cutting-edge of new features. Bear in mind that under [SemVer](http://semver.org/) (the versioning scheme that Node uses), breaking changes are only allowed in major-version releases - having a regular schedule for these coming out ensures that these changes can be tested before they get added to an LTS version further down the line.

For more info, I recommend taking a look at the [Node LTS GitHub](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS) - this is where I got all this information from, and it's a pretty helpful resource.